# Magento: SOLR: How to add custom product thumbnail image in auto complete dropdown

Tags: magento, solr, solr4

I would like to display custom image which is newly created ie., thumbnail attribute. Currently solr displays resized big image(300x200) so its not looks good. I want to display the image of product thumbnail which is proportionally cropped(100x100). Here is the example dropdown i'm getting.
[image]

Comment: What module do you use for solr, we need some more information on how this dropdown is displayed.

Comment: I'm using SolrBridge module @ChristofferBubach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `SolrBridge/Solrsearch/Model/Ultility.php` file for the method `generateThumb()` and change the width & height variables.

Possibly you might need to edit the CSS in file `skin/frontend/base/default/solrsearch/css/autocomplete.css` for the larger thumb to display correctly.

Comment: Great man! found the line where it need changes. Now it's working perfectly :)